Duplicate id Битрикс24 в табах
создаётся кастомный таб в карточке компании. В табе размещается грид с фильтром.
При использовании любого фильтра или пресета появляется ошибка типа:
"Duplicate id (company_12_timeline_history_search_container) for the BX.Main.Popup instance."

После перезагрузки страницы (F5) и повторного захода в таб карточки видим отфильтрованные данные с учетом выбранных ранее фильтров.
Так же при переключении на другие вкладки карточки компании (даже если отменить подключение вышеуказанной кастомной вкладки) в консоли появляются сообщения вида:
Possible BX.Event.EventEmitter memory leak detected. 30 "grid::updated" listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

Если данный компонент вставить в пустую страницу - все будет работать как надо и без ошибок.
Может кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой! Подскажите пожалуйста как ее можно решить?
